# What does "remain current on" mean?

Tags: meaning

> Contracts with third parties MUST include a clause that holds the
>   third party responsible for **remaining current on** and complying
>   with all relevant Disposal policies.

I have no idea what this "current on" means and what remaining thing that this third party have to be responsible for.. I searched but couldn't find any relevant result. Can anybody help me with this clause?

Does it mean to remain current on all the relevant policies, which means that the third party should remain up-to-date regarding the policies?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, your interpretation is correct.